# How can I get a copy of /var for SunOS 5.5.1

Tags: solaris

I had a problem on my SunOS 5.5.1 installation, so I tried to restore from a backup. After the restoration completed, `/var` was empty. I have another workstation with the same OS. How could I get a copy of `/var` from one machine to the other?

Comment: Why is /var empty ? How did you restore the file system ? Why are you using such an old and no more supported version of Solaris ?

Answer (score 1):

If you've lost everything in `/var`, you have nothing to lose by copying over the whole contents of `/var`. I wouldn't advise copying the files though, as many of them will be machine-specific or tied to a particular machine state and most will be created automatically as needed. What you need to have is the directory structure. On the working machine, run this as root:

```
cd /var
find . -type d | cpio -o >/tmp/var.cpio
```

Copy the file `var.cpio` to the damaged machine and run this as root:

```
cd /var
cpio -i </tmp/var.cpio
```

If you discover files that must be copied as well, add them to the `find` expression above.